# Collection.retainAll() works oddly

Tags: java

I currently have a problem with the function `.retainAll()`. The purpose is to find the `tokens` that are stored in `sortedTXT`.

Here is my code:

```
List<String> sortedTXT = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

// Some code 

sortedTXT.add(String someString);
tokens.add(String someString);

// Some code

System.out.println(tokens.size());
System.out.println(sortedTXT.size());

Collection<String> listTerms = sortedTXT;
   listTerms.retainAll(tokens);

System.out.println(tokens.size());
System.out.println(sortedTXT.size());
System.out.println(listTerms.size());
```

And here is the output. I don't understand why sortedTXT has been modified because I cast it into the listTerms to avoid any modifications on it. I tried also to declare listTerms as a `List`rather as a `Collection`. But I still get the same problem.

It is normal that listTerms is empty because none terms of sortedTXT is among the tokens. There is no Exception at all.

```
19
3

19
0
0
```

Comment: Assigning an object to another variable does not copy it: it is still the same object: `sortedTXT` and `listTerms` both point to the same object.

Comment: Try `Collection<String> listTerms = new ArrayList<>(sortedTXT);`

Comment: Nice explication Mark, thx! It works fine with your proposition tobias, thx guys